# Continuity type problem involving a limit?

Tags: limits, continuity

I am trying to solve this problem involving a limit / continuity.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/aglohigapdfalny/Screenshot%202013-10-30%2020.22.40.png

I've set the equations equal to each other and ended up with:

x^2 - 4x - 20 = 0

However, using the quadratic equation and getting both of the roots for x does not give me the right answer. Any idea on how to approach this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to subtract a $-12$, which makes it adding a $12$.  The result is
$$
x^2-4x+4=0.
$$